# Why I can't get my array from another class

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `Activity`, in which I have to use function from another class DataBase . In DataBase code have to get information from my **FireBase database**, and then return ArrayList as a result. But when I use function `takeDataFromFirebase` my array in `null`, it's size is `null`. How I can get the array with FireBase information to my activity?

```
public class DataBase{    
public ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> takeDataFromFirebase(DatabaseReference dRef) {
        usersRef = dRef.child(USERS_CHILD);
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String userKey = ds.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference messagesRef = usersRef.child(userKey).child(USER_MESSAGES);
                    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                messageText = dSnapshot.child(USER_MESSAGE_TEXT).getValue(String.class);
                                arrayList.add(messageText);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                    };
                    messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        return null;
    }
}
```

and my activity where I use this method:

```
public class Categories extends AppCompatActivity{


private static final String TAG = "CATEGORIES";
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private ListView all_problems_list_view;
private Button add_problem_button, signOut;
private static long back_pressed;


FirebaseDatabase mDataBase;
DatabaseReference dRef;
DatabaseReference userRef;
DataBase dataBaseFunctions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_categories);

    dataBaseFunctions = new DataBase();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dRef = mDataBase.getReference();
    userRef = dRef.child("Users");
    //region add all items

    all_problems_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(id.all_problems_list_view);
    add_problem_button = (Button) findViewById(id.add_problem_button);
    signOut = (Button) findViewById(id.SignOutBut);
    //endregion

    //region set onClick to buttons
    signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logout();
        }
    });

    add_problem_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Categories.this, sendEmailActivity.class));
        }
    });


    //endregiond



    ArrayList<String> list = dataBaseFunctions.takeDataFromFirebase(dRef);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    all_problems_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Comment: `takeDataFromFirebase` returns `null` so what did you expected? as in thousands of similar questions the answer is: you should learn how to work with asynchronous APIs(using callbacks)

Comment: I rewrote my code, add asynchrons method `doInBackground`, but i don't unuderstand why my array is null, sorry for this stupid question, but be a loyal, i'm just beginner. How can i return info which i download to my Activity? What i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your function takeDataFromFirebase returns null so your result will be always null.. Replace this null by the array you want to get, arrayList i guess.

Comment: Exuse me, but i am beginner and don't understand why my array return null. I return to log value of the `messageText` and it return me all needed information. But how i can return this info, when i use this method?

Comment: On your function `takeDataFromFirebase`, the only return you have is "null". So when you call it, the result will be null !
I see that you fill `arraylist` on DataBase class. I guess it is this array that you try to get on Categories class.
To get it, it's litle bit more complicated, you have to implement a listener on your second class which will detect when arraylist is modified and will update your adaptater.